# Geometry- Trigonometry question

Tags: trigonometry

So I’m struggling to understand how to find the angle in this circle, we’ve  recently learnt about trigonometry and like finding the area of a circle and all that but I can’t seem to remember which formula I have to use to find this angle. Can anyone lend a helping hand? 
[image]

Comment: This is straightforward with, for example, the sines theorem or the cosines theorem....and you tagged your question trigonometry, so...

Comment: Maybe  a figure is missing here? Could you provide further details?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the theorem of cosines:
$$10^2=7^2+7^2-2\cdot 7^2\cos(\angle{AOB})$$

Answer (score 2):

You can bisect the angle AOB, which divides isosceles triangle AOB into two right triangles. Each one of these right triangles has a hypotenuse of 7 and a leg of 5, so the sine of their angle at O is 5/7. As such, the measure of angle AOB is 2*arcsin(5/7).

Answer (score 1):

You have an isosceles triangle with two sides as the radius of 7.  This is because they tell you O is the center.  Then you have $\sin(\theta/2)=5/7$.  So the angle is $\sin^{-1}(5/7)*2$

Comment: Typesetting tip:  Type `$\sin x$` to obtain $\sin x$.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You’d think after all my latek typing I’d not give an italic sin...yes, noted, thanks.